# Why the arc results with opencv hough circle so different?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

There are two binary images about lines and arcs. The first is the original image, and the second one has changed the height of the original image and filled it with black. The arc has not changed. And then call opencv hough circle detection function with the two images. The parameters are the same, but the results are very different. It seems that the detection results are related to the image size. I took a cursory look at the relevant source code of opencv and could not find the  reason. I'm confused, please help me, thank you very much!

result image 1:
[image: result image 1]

result image 2:
[image: result image 2]

Test with opencv-python 4.8.0.76

My test code here

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mask = cv2.imread(r'new\07.jpg', 0)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(mask, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=10, param1=200, param2=9, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
    circles = circles.astype(np.int32)

    show_circle = mask.copy()
    show_circle = cv2.cvtColor(show_circle, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    max_n = 1
    for cnt, i in enumerate(circles[0, :]):
        center = (i[0], i[1])
        radius = i[2]
        cv2.circle(show_circle, center, radius, [0, 255, 0], 2)
        print(f'radius = {radius}')
        if cnt >= max_n-1:
            break

    # Save image
    cv2.imwrite(f"output/circle.png", show_circle)
```

Test images here
[ori image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyrjx.jpg)
[changed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMa3c.jpg)

Comment: This Hough transform method requires the center of the circle to be inside the image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo THX for your answer, I found the code about center filter in HoughCirclesFindCentersInvoker just like you said that the center of the circle must  be inside the image. As described in the previous question, we need to find the center of a circle with a large radius. Do you have some idea about it?   Thanks again